# Difference between uniform initialization vs new operator

Tags: c++, memory-management, heap-memory, new-operator

Let's assume that I have the following class:

```
Class Foo {
public:
    int j;
    Foo(int i){
        j = i;
        std::cout << j << endl;
    };
}
```

I am new to C++ and I'm confused about whether the following two blocks of code perform the same activity regarding memory allocation. I remember learning that **new** allocates memory dynamically but I am not sure about the first block. Is the first block doing the same?

```
Foo foo{2};
```

```
Foo *foo2;
foo2 = new Foo(2);
```

Comment: One creates an *automatic* object `foo`, the other defines a *pointer* `foo2`, then allocates a dynamic object and stores the address of that object as the pointer's value. If you're new to this language I *strongly* urge a good book.

Comment: Foo doesn't have any values in it so you aren't initializing anything. The constructor only prints the `i` passed. the `foo2=new Foo(2);` does allocate an object but only because c++ doesn't allow a completely empty class object.

Comment: @WhozCraig Can you recommend any?

Comment: @doug I update my question to have the constructor initialize the class member j.

Comment: probably should be `j=i;`

Comment: @IsaacMartinezJr.Mora You can refer to a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Please don't tag c in c++ questions

Comment: One should write `Foo(int i) : j(i) { }` and also `Foo *foo2 = new Foo(2);`. However, in modern code, one should prefer using `std::unique_ptr<Foo> foo(2)` instead. **Read a few books on C++** to learn the language and good pratices.

Answer (score 0):

##### Case 1

Here we consider:

```
Foo foo{2}; //this will create an object of type `Foo` on the stack
```

The above statement will create an object of type `Foo` on the stack using the **converting constructor** `Foo::Foo(int)`.

##### Case 2

Here we consider:

```
Foo *foo2;           //creates a pointer of type `Foo*` on the stack
foo2 = new Foo(2);   //assign foo2 the pointer returned from new Foo(2)
```

Here first we create a pointer named `foo2` of type `Foo*` on the stack. Note that as of now this pointer is **uninitialized**.

Next, when we write `foo2 = new Foo(2);` the following things happen:

1. Due to `new Foo(2)` an object of type `Foo` is created on the heap using the converting constructor `Foo::Foo(int)`.
2. Next, a pointer to that dynamically allocated object is returned.
3. This returned pointer is assigned to `foo2` on the left hand side.

---

Note also that instead of assigning `i` to `j`  inside the constructor you can instead initialize `j` in the constructor initializer list as shown below:

```
Class Foo {
public:
    int j;
//--------------vvvv--------------> initialize j in the member initializer list
    Foo(int i): j(i){
       
        std::cout << j << endl;
    };
}
```